# How to convert a timestamp to a bigint in milliseconds

Tags: sql, timestamp, presto, trino

I have the following SQL:

```
select cast(to_unixtime(date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp)) AS bigint);
```

So basically I always go back to the top of the hour, take that timestamp and try to get the unix time for it.

However, this is printing value like so which is in seconds: **1708473600** but I want it to be in milliseconds something like **1708473600000**.

I dont seem to find an example in Trino documentation on how to do this. They have a to_millisecond method that takes an interval. I just want to provide a timestamp and get the epoch unix time in ms.

Answer (score 1):

Unix epoch time does NOT have millisecond precision as part of its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) so there is also no function for doing that.

However you can just write a [SQL routine](https://trino.io/docs/current/routines.html) to do the conversion for you, or you can just do it each time. The math for it is just to multiply the value with 1000.

So in your example query

```
SELECT cast(to_unixtime(date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp)) AS bigint) * 1000;
```

Or

```
SELECT cast(to_unixtime(date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp))*1000 AS bigint);
```